# Dropdown menu in VueJS (toggling of active menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

This is the menu and below my navigation menu and method that on click should open the subitems inside nav item on click but I cant seem to be find where I'm lacking

[![dropdown_menu][1]][1]

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
//menu
        "menu_title": "a",
        "child_routes": [{
            "path": "/a1",
            "menu_title": "a1"
          },
          {
            "path": "/a2",
            "menu_title": "a2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "menu_title": "b",
        "child_routes": [{
            "path": "/b1",
            "menu_title": "b1"
          },
          {
            "path": "/b2",
            "menu_title": "b2"
          },
          {
            "path": "/b1",
            "menu_title": "b3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "menu_title": "c",
        "child_routes": [{
            "path": "/c1",
            "menu_title": "c1"
          },
          {
            "path": "/c2",
            "menu_title": "c2"
          },
          {
            "path": "/c3",
            "menu_title": "c3"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      navlinks() {
        var navItemParent = document.querySelector("nav-item");
        var navLink = document.querySelector(".idb-nav .nav-item .nav-link");
        var navItem = document.querySelector(".idb-nav .nav-item");
        navItem.classList.toggle("active");

        if (navItem.contains("active")) {
          navItem.classList.remove("active");
          navLink.classList.toggle("active");
        }

      }

    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <nav class="idb-sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="idb-nav list-unstyled m-15 p-0">
      <template v-for="(menu, index) in sideBarLinks.routes">
     <li class="nav-item" v-if="menu.child_routes!=null" :key="index">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" @click="navlinks"  >
       <i :class="menu.menu_icon" class="menu-icon"></i>
       <span class="menu-title">{{menu.menu_title}}</span>
      </a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled sub-menu">
       <router-link 
        :to="subMenu.path" 
        tag="li" 
        v-for="(subMenu, key) in menu.child_routes" 
        :key="key"
       >
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sub-menu-nav-link">
         <span>{{subMenu.menu_title}}</span>
        </a>
       </router-link>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <router-link 
      :key="index" 
      :to="menu.path" 
      tag="li" 
      class="nav-item" 
      v-else
     >
      <a class="nav-link">
       <i :class="menu.menu_icon" class="mr-15"></i>
       <span class="menu-title">{{menu.menu_title }}</span>
      </a>
     </router-link>
    </template>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: There's one issue the active class should toggle on click of nav-item

Answer (score 0):

The classes toggling should be managed as part of the `data`. Try this and see if it works for you:

### HTML

```html
<div id="app">
   <nav class="idb-sidebar-nav">
      <ul class="idb-nav list-unstyled m-15 p-0">
         <template v-for="(menu, index) in sideBarLinks.routes" :key="index">
            <li class="nav-item"
                  v-if="menu.child_routes && menu.child_routes.length">

               <a :class="[ 'nav-link', { 'active': menu.active } ]"
                  href="javascript:void(0);"
                  @click="toggleMenu(index)">

                  <i :class="menu.menu_icon" class="menu-icon"></i>
                  <span class="menu-title">{{menu.menu_title}}</span>
               </a>

               <ul class="list-unstyled sub-menu">
                  <router-link tag="li"
                               v-for="(subMenu, key) in menu.child_routes"
                               :key="key"
                               :to="subMenu.path">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub-menu-nav-link">
                        <span>{{subMenu.menu_title}}</span>
                     </a>
                  </router-link>
               </ul>
            </li>

            <router-link v-else
                         :key="index"
                         :to="menu.path"
                         tag="li"
                         class="nav-item">

               <a :class="[ 'nav-link', { 'active': menu.active } ]"
                  href="javascript:void(0);"
                  @click="toggleMenu(index)">

                  <i :class="menu.menu_icon" class="mr-15"></i>
                  <span class="menu-title">{{menu.menu_title }}</span>
               </a>

            </router-link>
         </template>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

### routes.json

For improved readability and maintainability, you'd best be moving the list to separate file.

```
[
   {
      "menu_title": "a",
      "child_routes": [
         {
            "path": "/a1",
            "menu_title": "a1"
         },
         {
            "path": "/a2",
            "menu_title": "a2"
         }
      ],
      active: true // First item opened by default (if you like)
   },
   {
      "menu_title": "b",
      "child_routes": [
         {
            "path": "/b1",
            "menu_title": "b1"
         },
         {
            "path": "/b2",
            "menu_title": "b2"
         },
         {
            "path": "/b1",
            "menu_title": "b3"
         }
      ],
      active: false
   },
   {
      // ...
   }
]
```

### app.js

```
import * as routes from './routes.json';

const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',

   data() {
      return {
         sideBarLinks: {
            routes
         }
      }
   },

   methods: {
      toggleSidebar(index) {
         this.sideBarLinks
            .routes
            .forEach((menu, i) => menu.active = (i === index));
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . I also want to know how can i remove the class active when from the current added active class if clicked on another nav-item . Presently with every click the active class keeps on adding onto the nav-item . If Clicked on one item it should remove active class from previous and add onto the current nav-item which is been clicked

Comment: @Aishwerya Please try my solution above, the `toggleSidebar` method should do the class switching job for you. The `.active` class will never be added multiple times.

Comment: Be sure to add the initial `active: false` item onto the individual items though.

Comment: i have added image in your code , after follwing the steps you guided me .. but turns out the class is been added on every nav-item . My question is can we just add only once for example if clicked on first nav-item should be added on first and if clicked on second nav-item removed from first nav-item and add on second nav-item which is been clicked

Comment: OK, it sounds like you want only one active `nav-link` per click, and the siblings deactivated or collapsed. This should be straightforward. I'll get back to this when I get home.

Comment: @Aishwerya Answer updated. Please check it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: If it helped, please mark it as resolved. Thanks! :)

Comment: There's one issue the active class should toggle on click of nav-item

Comment: Anyone know the solution?